# Using TFS Labels like SourceSafe Labels

Tags: tfs

We have a fairly standard release procedure using Visual Source Safe for labeling a build before it is released. This allows us to do a get from that label if there are any problems and use it to branch if changes are necessary.

We have several different projects and always label using the builds version number.
e.g. "V1.0"

After moving some projects to TFS we have noticed that if you try to label using the same version number as another solution e.g. Solution A and Solution B both release "V1.5" then TFS will not let you do this as the Label name is treated globally. After reading a few blogs on the subject which discusses how TFS labels are not a point in time but a collection of files I am thinking that we will have to start including the project name in the label to get around this e.g. label as "Project A V1.5" and "Project B V1.5". Does this sound like the right approach?

Comment: Well, they're not a collection of files; they're a collection of _versions_ of files. Still, that fact is not the source of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't read Brian Harry's [Why TFS labels aren't like SourceSafe labels](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2005/11/18/494439.aspx), please do.

Basically the answer to your question is YES!

Comment: Yes I did read this, I think I just wanted another developer to say yes :)