# TFS get latest label programmatically

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am using powershell to make an email utility to keep track of changesets that occurred since the last version.

I am trying to search for changesets between the last label created for the specified workspace and the latest changeset

I am retrieving the latest changeset using the code

```
$latestChangeset = Get-TfsItemHistory -HistoryItem $workSpacePath -Recurse -Server $tfs -Stopafter 1
```

I have tried using `tf labels` command line commands but I cannot find any way to make it return only the latest build label of a specific workspace

Answer (score 2):

You can involve [TFS API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146(v=vs.120).aspx) in PowerShell to get the latest label.

```
$CollectionUrl = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/tfs/defaultcollection"
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($CollectionUrl)
$vcs = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])
$labels = $vcs.QueryLabels('*','$/ProjectName',$null,$true)
$lastlabel = $labels | Select-Object -last 1
write-host $lastlabel.Name
write-host $lastlabel.LabelID
```

Answer (score 0):

That may be because labels in TFS are not as in previous source code repositories like VSS. Take a look at the blog linked in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9873927/3083213).

Quoting the blog post:

> Labels in SourceSafe were always “point in time” labels.  You generally labeled some tree at some point in time and that implied a label of all of the contents of the tree at the same point in time.

and

> In Team Foundation, labels are more powerful.  Instead of being a single point in time, they are able to have versions of each file in the label from different points in time.

So, relating labels to changesets will be problematic.